# Add class to ASP.NET MasterPage control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

This is the code in my `MasterPage`:

```
<li id="liABOUT" runat="server"><a href="About.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
```

When I am on another page referencing the `MasterPage` I want to add a class to this `li` control, something like this. Cant get it to work. Using ASP.NET 4.5

```
Me.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderMaster").FindControl("LiAbout").Attributes.Add("class", "active")
```

VB.NET or C# Code would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked....

```
' Get reference to control located on master page
 Dim lb As HtmlGenericControl = Page.Master.FindControl("liABOUT")
 lb.Attributes.Add("class", "active")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a public property in your `MasterPage` :

```
public String LiAboutClass
{
    get { return liABOUT.Attributes["class"]; }
    set { liABOUT.Attributes["class"] = value; }
}
```

Access this property in your `ContentPage`:

```
var siteMaster = (SiteMaster)this.Master;
if (siteMaster != null) siteMaster.LiAboutClass = "active";
```

**Edit**: Also you can use [`MasterType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274(VS.80).aspx). it allows you to access the `MasterTypes` properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I first converted it to HtmlGenericControl and then added attribute.

```
(Master.FindControl("liABOUT") as HtmlGenericControl).Attributes.Add("class", "active");
```

Comment: Not sure how to use this now, some code is still missing.

Comment: Are you able to get the "Master" object? What is the error that u get?